# Best way to filter datetime2 with a date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I have a column that is `datetime2` and I want to filter using a `date` variable. Currently I use:

`where mystringCol in ('x', 'y', 'z') and cast(MyDatetimeCol as date) > @MyDateVariable`.

In the execution plan it is using a seek on the covering nonclustered index on `(mystringCol, MyDatetimeCol)` which has seleral columns in the `include` part.
Regarding the predicate being SARGABLE. So it seems it is SARGABLE even though it is doing everything wrong, i.e. using a function (`cast`) and using `in`?

Also do I need the `cast`?

Comment: Why `CAST` the column `MyDatetimeCol` here at all? If it because you don't want values that are on the same date as `@MyDateVariable`? Is so, why not just increase the day of `@MyDateVariable` by 1 and use `>=`?

Comment: `DATE` conversions [are indeed sometimes SARGable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea) as a special case in the optimizer. The `IN` is trivially SARGable as it's internally rewritten as a series of equality comparisons with `OR` clauses (`mystringCol = 'x' OR myStringCol = 'y' ...`) This in itself does not guarantee an efficient plan, of course.

Comment: @Larnu It is `cast`ed because I wanted to be 100% sure it worked and it was before I learned about SARGABLE... I will remove the cast... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If seems like you're overly complicating things here. The only reason I can see why you would cast `MyDatetimeCol` a date in the expression `MyDatetimeCol > @MyDateVariable` is so that a value like `'2020T-11-03T11:00:00` returns false when `@MyDateVariable` has the value `20201103`.

If that *is* the case, instead of using `>` use `>=` and increase the value of `@MyDateVariable` by one, then it is symantically the same:

```sql
DECLARE @MyDateVariable date = '20201104'; --was 20201103 before

SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
  AND MyDatetimeCol >= @MyDateVariable;
```

`CAST(MyDatetimeCol AS date) > @MyDateVariable` and `MyDatetimeCol >= DATEADD(DAY,1,@MyDateVariable)` are effectively synonyms, apart from that the latter will be more performant.

Comment: Thanks,  it has to be `> @MyDateVariable`. `@MyDateVariable` is 30 days back in time which I calculated in the script...